# Reading file one by one and call api only after first file is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

Here is my code which will read the files one by one and display its content and it will return once all files are read.

Here i want to call api whenever 1 file is read fully

Here's the an example content of 3 files. Don't consider all file will have filenumber.txt. its just an example

```
**1.txt**
_____
1-one
1-two
1-three
_____
**2.txt**
_____
2-one
2-two
2-three
_____
**3.txt**
_____
3-one
3-two
3-three
```

Here's my Router to read and display all the text

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');


var arr = [];

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  for (let index = 1; index <= 3; index++) {
    arr.push(readFile('public/file/'+index+'.txt'));
    console.log(index);
  }
  Promise.all((arr))
  .then(function (results) {
    console.log('done!')
    res.send('respond with a resource');
  });
});
```

file read function

```
function readFile(name){
  return fs.readFile(name, "utf8",function(err, data) {
    console.log(name,data);
  });
}
```

on the promise `Promise.all((arr))` it will return once all files is read. From here i want to call an api for each line on the file.

The next file should be read only after all the api call for current files is read.

Here's the api call function

```
const axios = require('axios');
function doApi(url){
  var url = `https://run.mocky.io/v3/url?prod=${url}`
  var config = { method : 'get', url : url, headers : {}, data : {}};
  return axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log('prod',url,response.data)
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log('err1');
  })
}
```

**Note :**

It should be like

**Step 1 :** Read first file , the read data will be like

```
1-one
1-two
1-three
```

**Step 2 :**  Now, call the do api

```
// These 3 api's can be ran concurrently, but file read should be done one by one only
https://run.mocky.io/v3/url?prod=${1-one}
https://run.mocky.io/v3/url?prod=${1-two}
https://run.mocky.io/v3/url?prod=${1-three}
```

Repeat the **Step 1** for second file.

How can i achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read each file 1 by 1 in a loop, initialising Promise objects to handle the doApiCall() passing the contents of the file (the url parameter), and adding them to a Promises array.

When all files are read, issue `Promise.all(promises)`.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let filepaths = ['filepath1', 'filepath2', '...' , 'filepathN'];

  let concurrentAPICalls = [];

  for (let fp of filepaths) {
    let fileContents = readFileSynchro(fp);  // no await

    for (let line of fileContents.split('\n')) {
       // initialise promise to issue REST call with url inside file
       concurrentAPICalls.push(new Promise(line).then(doApiCall).catch(apiError)));
    }
  }

  // execute all promises after reading files 1 by 1
  // best effort (don't drop remaining on first failure)
  Promise.allSettled(concurrentAPICalls).then(() => res.send('all files processed'));
});
```